# ASP.Net MVC: How do I Reuse Views and Partials With Different Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the need to display different form fields depending on the type of user that I am saving.

I have some user types and some of the user types have the same data, so you can imagine the following (with the potential for a lot more types):

1. TypeA: Name, Password, etc., LinkedToLegacySystemA, LegacySystemAUserId
2. TypeB: Name, Password, etc., LinkedToLegacySystemB, LegacySystemBUserId
3. TypeC: Name, Password, etc., LinkedToLegacySystemC, LegacySystemCUserId, LegacySystemCAdminLevel

When I create a new user I may be in the context of any of these systems, but I know exactly what system I am connected to (there's a specific Controller for CRUD on each type of user), but I want to share views (if possible).  So I've got this: TypeAUserController, TypeBUserController, TypeCUserController, each with their own Create, Retrieve, Update, and Delete Get/Post Actions.

**So the basic question is "How Can I Reuse Views To Display Create For Each User?"**

Edit:
For further clarification, there's shared information for each user, this is the view I want to share. The ideas that I had come up with to date assumed that the differences between models would be encapsulated in a partial view and each potential model has its own view. So we're looking at a single Page-Level model for each CRUD operation on a user and then a single submodel for each child model that encapsulates the differences.
This is not a good approach for reasons listed below already.

Comment: It's difficult to say given how vague you've been.  Views should be strongly typed to your model.  If you have different models, you should have different views.  But, you could always have a viewmodel that includes all of them.  Of you could have a base class which all view models inherit from, then use EditorTemplates to render the specific types.  However, all these have various issues that you need to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, I added my own answers for what I've brainstormed.  They match what you suggest and you're right, they each have their own issues :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how this actually got implemented...

3 page-level "display" models for the GET on each CRUD, each which

- CreateLegacyUserAModel

  - SharedUserModel Model (this one has data annotations on it for validation)
  - LegacyUserAModel (this one has data annotations on it for validation)
- ...
- CreateLegacyUserCModel

  - ...

Then the views:

- CreateLegacyView (uses CreateLegacyUserAModel, handles creating the form)

  - SharedUserFieldsView (uses SharedUserModel)
  - LegacyUserFieldsView (uses LegacyUserAModel)

*We pretty much flipped the Views/Models.*

Cons

- Need a View and specific model for each CRUD operation (4 * n DisplayModels)
- One POST for each CRUD operation (not really a con, honestly, this makes sense to me)

Pros

- No need to cast any models anywhere, no casts in the views and no casts in the POST actions

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution 1:
Pass this model to the View

- CreateUserPageModel

  - BoringModelWithSharedStuff
  - LegacySystemAModel
  - LegacySystemBModel
  - LegacySystemCModel
  - PartialName

Then in the view use the partial name to decide which partial to display and choose a non-null model to pass to it.

When submitting the form it would submit to a page with a custom model binder that would choose the correct model.

Benefits:

- Allows The parent view to be reused
- Differences in the Models are placed in different partials

Cons:

- View has to find the filled child model to pass to the partial
- PartialName has to be passed and so a path has to be chosen in the controller

Comment: Having a shared model that needs to be edited for every new legacy system seems like a bad pattern. There has to be a way to leave the model for legacy system a through c untouched when adding legacy system d

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution 2: Use the view bag.

The model would be super simple:

- CreateUserPageModel

  - SharedDataModel

The view would then check the Viewbag for information as to which partial it would load, either by specifying the partial name or providing an enumeration for the view to switch on.
The partial would then cast the item in the viewbag to a specific type.

Benefits:

- Allows The parent view to be reused
- Differences in the Models are placed in different partials

Cons:

- View has to pick the correct partial to load
- Partial has to cast to its known type

Comment: Also, when submitting the form this would require a custom model binder that would choose the correct model, effectively figuring out what to cast to again.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution 3: Use a marker interface

- CreateUserPageModel

  - SharedDataModel
  - ILegacyUserDataModel
  - PartialName

The View loads a partial based on the passed model and then passes the ILegacyUserDataModel to the partial. The partial would then cast to whatever model it was designed for.

Benefits:

- Allows The parent view to be reused
- Differences in the Models are placed in different partials

Cons:

- PartialName has to be passed and so a path has to be chosen in the controller
- Partial has to cast from the interface to the real type for which it was designed

Comment: I really do not like the idea of using a marker interface, it feels dirty

Comment: Also, when submitting the form this would require a custom model binder that would choose the correct model, effectively figuring out what to cast to again.